# 'children' doesn´t work in Flutter, problem of dependencies?

Tags: flutter

```
//My code show error in 'children', i try to change for 'child' but doesn´t work

 class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar:
        AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.indigo, title: Text("Bem-Vindo")),
        body: Center(children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Error in Children
I try to put two buttons in the middle of screen
I have try to change to 'child'

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with dependencies.
You cannot use **children** for the Center widget.
Use a **Row** if you want them aligned horizontally or a **Column** if you want them aligned vertically.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar:
        AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.indigo, title: Text("Bem-Vindo")),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: null,
               ),
               RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: null,
               ),
            ])
          )
        );
  }
}
```